# Matlab: strings aren't really strings?

Tags: string, matlab, pdf

I have a script that is printing images to a file. I want the name of the file that I print to to be dynamic - ie I want the output file name to depend on some parameters. Kind of like this:

```
outputFileNames = {'1.0' '1.25' '1.75'};

%....some code to determine which outputFileName I should use

f=figure('visible','off');  

%.....code to populate figure .....

fname = strcat('prefix', outputFileNames(index),'suffix');
print(f,'-dpsc2', '-append',fname)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error using LocalCheckHandles (line 81)
Handle input argument contains non-handle value(s).

Error in print>LocalCreatePrintJob (line 366)
handles = checkArgsForHandleToPrint(0, varargin{:});

Error in print (line 160)
[pj, inputargs] = LocalCreatePrintJob(varargin{:});

Error in GenerateFieldPlots (line 57)
print(f,'-dpsc2', '-append',fname)
```

When I check the value of fname I get `prefix1.0suffix` (as desired) and when I check the value of `index` I get `1`. If I replace `fname = strcat('prefix', outputFileNames(index),'suffix');` with `fname = strcat('prefix', '1.0','suffix');` The program runs fine and outputs to the expected file name.

Last attempt at making sense of this:

```
fname = strcat('prefix', outputFileNames(index),'suffix');
class(fname)
```

yields `char`, and

```
fname = strcat('prefix', '1.0','suffix');
class(fname)
```

also yields `char`.

My questions:

1. Why is this happening? Is my array of strings not really an array of strings?
2. How do I fix this? IE, how can I make the output file's name dynamic?
3. Above issues come about because I have a *lot* (>5GB) of data that I need to convert into plots and save to files. Ultimately I need all these plots in a single document that can be opened on any PC (like... pdf!). To accomplish this I'm appending all my figures as individual pages to a postscript file and then converting the ps to pdf. Unfortunately ps's are not very space-efficient, so I'm ending up with a *giant* .ps file. Above is my attempt to break up a single *giant* .ps into several smaller ones which I can convert to pdf's in turn (and then combine into a single pdf). Such an approach is very convoluted, but I have been unable to find a better way. Do you have a suggestion for a better way to accomplish my task?

Please let me know if I've left out any details that might be helpful. I'm new to Matlab and this is my first SO post regarding Matlab!

Comment: Just had a thought: could this be a security issue? Is changing the output file name within the code a no-no?

Comment: Are you certain the error message is due to your `fname`. To me it rather seems there's something wrong with your figure-handle. Try replacing `fname` by a fixed name, say, `"foo.ps"` and check wether the file is printed...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
>> x = strcat('aaa',{'bbb'},'ccc')
x = 
    'aaabbbccc'

>> class(x)
ans =
cell
```

I think you meant to write:

```
fname = strcat('prefix', outputFileNames{index}, 'suffix');
```

or simply:

```
fname = ['prefix', outputFileNames{index}, 'suffix'];
```

Note the use of braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: Note that `strcat` can be useful to construct cell array of strings like: `strcat('stack', {'over','under'}, 'flow')`. Otherwise I prefer to use simple concatenation if building regular strings

Comment: I didn't even realize that there existed a distinction between the braces and the parentheses. I assumed that `outputFileNames` was Matlab's equivalent of an array, and one used parentheses to access elements of the array. Could you direct me to a source that discusses Matlab's data structures and differentiates between `[ `and `{`?

Comment: @alexvas: Cell arrays are the equivalent of arrays for heterogeneous types. This is because numeric arrays can only store elements of the same type. [This page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) explains how to access data in cell arrays. Also here is the [main page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) for cell arrays containing links to all related topics.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have something else named fname on your MATLAB path?

Try

`which -all fname`

This will tell you if this is a name used elsewhere.

Comment: Definitely not. The above code excerpts show every occurrence of the text 'fname' within the script. Also, `which -all fname` just returns `fname is a variable`.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that `class(fname)` returns `char` and not `string`:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strings.html :

> S = `'Any Characters'` creates a character array, or string. The string is actually a vector that contains the numeric codes for the characters (codes 0 to 127 are ASCII). The length of S is the number of characters.

I don't see any reason why your code wouldn't work. Are you sure about that `index` being `1`? You can put breakpoints and inspect value of variables while pausing the code. I'd put one where the error occurs, or maybe some lines earlier. More help on debugging: [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).

Comment: I understand that I was to expect `char` rather than `string` - but the purpose of me including those outputs was to show that in both cases `fname` was a `char` - so the error can't be due to some variable type exceptions.